# What is the real name of a "parrot clock"

Tags: word-request

Some twenty, thirty years ago every family had that kind of clock with a mechanical parrot inside, and every time on the hour the door to its nest would open, then the parrot would come out and go "tweet, tweet, tweet". Sometimes it would be a couple dancing to the music.

I had thought that it might be called a "parrot clock", but when I searched that on google all I got is regular desk clocks with parrot pictures on their faces. So what is it really called? Thanks!

Comment: *Cuckoo clock* came to mind.

Comment: @DamkerngT. That's exactly what I'm looking for! I had thought that they use the sculpture of parrots all over the world...

Comment: The cuckoo clocks I know of make a noise that sounds like *cuckoo.* If you heard a clock sound *teeet tweet tweet,* it might not be a cuckoo clock, but some other kind of mechanical clock. A clock with a dancing couple is not a cuckoo clock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called **cuckoo clock**.

According to a Wikipedia page, [Cuckoo clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_clock):

> A **cuckoo clock** is a typically pendulum-regulated clock traditionally manufactured in the Black Forest in Germany that strikes the hours with a sound like a common cuckoo's call and often has a mechanical cuckoo that emerges with each note. The mechanism to produce the cuckoo call was installed in almost every kind of cuckoo clock since the middle of the 18th century and has remained almost without variation, until the present.

The word cuckoo clock brings back a lot of good memories of mine, such as those I had when I read stories for children or when I watched animations (back then commonly called "cartoons"). To refresh those memories, I searched a bit, and found this awesome photo I'd like to share:

[image]
<sup>Source: ["Cuckoo Clock" taken by Churchil Angelio](https://flic.kr/p/85UG1D).</sup>

Cuckoo clocks are always charming!